# Как с помощью модуля win_unzip распаковать много архивов?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, zip, ansible

Есть папка с кучей zip-файлов. В каждом архиве - прога и справка к ней. Периодически некоторые архивы обновляются. Как сделать, чтобы работало вот так:

```
- win_unzip:
    src: '{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\soft\*.zip'
    dest: '{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\soft\'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была задача распаковать zip-архивы скачанные с http://www.nirsoft.net/. Список файлов получил с помощью модуля [win_find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_find_module.html). Как всё увязать - подсмотрел [тут](http://www.mydailytutorials.com/using-ansible-find-module-search-filesfolder/).

```yaml
---
  - name: Install NirSoft
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    serial:
      - "100%"
    tasks:

    - name: Install\Update NirSoft 4 Windows
      when: ansible_os_family == 'Windows'
      become: yes
      become_method: runas
      become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
      block:
        - win_file:
            path: '%ProgramFiles%\nirsoft\'
            state: directory
        - win_path:
            elements:
              - '%ProgramFiles%\nirsoft\'
            state: present
        - win_find:
            paths: \\10.10.10.10\soft\nirsoft
            patterns: ['*.zip']
            get_checksum: no
          register: nirsoft_find_zips
        - win_unzip:
            src: '{{ item.path }}'
            dest: '{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\nirsoft\'
          with_items: "{{ nirsoft_find_zips.files }}"
```